# Mysql Count record instances in foreign table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in these structure:

```
Orders

-------------------------------------------------------
| id | description | created_by | price | created_at  | etc
-------------------------------------------------------

Sample data:
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | description | created_by | price | created_at  | 
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |   test 1    |   2        | 10.00 | 2015-10-10 00:00:00
| 2  |   test 2    |   1        | 20.00 | 2015-11-10 00:00:00
| 3  |   test 3    |   3        | 5.00  | 2015-12-10 00:00:00
| 4  |   test 4    |   10       | 100.00| 2015-01-10 00:00:00
```

And the other table

```
OrderStatus

------------------------------------
| orderid | status | comment      |
------------------------------------

------------------------------------
| orderid | status | comment      |
------------------------------------
| 1       | 1      | This is pending payment|
| 2       | 1      | This is pending payment|
| 1       | 2      |                        |
| 1       | 3      | Canceled due to shipment delay  |
| 2       | 2      | This is pending payment|
| 3       | 1      | This is pending payment|
| 4       | 1      | This is pending payment|
| 4       | 2      |                        |
| 4       | 4      | This is delivered      |
```

Possible values of status are: Pending: 1, PaymentMade: 2, Canceled: 3, Delivered: 4, etc

My desire is to create query/queries that returns:

```
Orders stats
--------------------------------------------------------------
| total | pending |   paid     | canceled  |    delivered    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
  4        1             1            1            1
```

So far, I've come up with these:

```
#total
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.id) FROM tbl_order a inner join tbl_order_status b on a.id=b.orderid

#pending
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.id) FROM tbl_order a inner join tbl_order_status b on a.id=b.orderid where b.status=1

#paid
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.id) FROM tbl_order a inner join tbl_order_status b on a.id=b.orderid where b.status=2

#canceled
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.id) FROM tbl_order a inner join tbl_order_status b on a.id=b.orderid where b.status=3

#delivered
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.id) FROM tbl_order a inner join tbl_order_status b on a.id=b.orderid where b.status=4
```

The first query result (total) is as expected but the rest all return inaccurate results

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT It's not a good performance pratice... Try use GROUP BY instead.

```
SELECT status, COUNT(1) FROM tbl_order a inner join tbl_order_status b on a.id=b.orderid GROUP BY b.status
```

This will result in **n** status rows, so you can grep all the sum of each type ;)

Comment: Thanks @user3558040, I removed the distinct and tried your suggestion, but this would combine counts for pending as 4, but which is not accurate as I should be getting 1. For instance, since order 1 has a most current status value of 3, its previous statuses of 1 and 2 should not be considered....

Answer (score 0):

Well I got around/solved it with this solution:

```
select status, count(status) from(
SELECT orderid,max(status) as status FROM tbl_order a 
inner join tbl_order_status b on a.id=b.orderid 
GROUP BY b.orderid 
order by b.orderid,b.status desc) t group by status;
```

Could there be performance enhancements to this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need a conditional aggregation  -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total,
       COUNT(IF(b.status=1, a.id, null)) pending,
       COUNT(IF(b.status=2, a.id, null)) paid,
       COUNT(IF(b.status=3, a.id, null)) cancel,
       COUNT(IF(b.status=4, a.id, null)) delivered,
  FROM tbl_order a inner join tbl_order_status b on a.id=b.orderid
```